# Deallocating layers and sprites in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I have a simple game structure with multiple GameScenes containing GameLayer and BackgroundLayer. The GameLayer has CCSprites added to it. Nothing gets removed or added during the game.

I'm unsure the best way to make sure everything is deallocated properly. Can I just call `[GameScene release]` to release the contained GameLayer and BackgroundLayer each time I change scene? Does deallocating the GameScene deallocate all the contained children? Is there a systematic approach to deallocating in cocos2d to make sure you've covered everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you send retain or copy to one of the Cocos2D nodes, you don't need to do anything. When you change the scene via CCDirector replaceScene, Cocos2D will clean up that scene for you.

You could also simply start using ARC (automatic reference counting) where these considerations are a thing of the past. To be able to do that you will have to use a [specially modified version of Cocos2D](http://www.tinytimgames.com/2011/07/22/cocos2d-and-arc/) or simply use [Kobold2D, which supports ARC](http://www.kobold2d.com) out of the box. In fact, it's enabled by default in all Kobold2D example projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the scene and layers (any cocos2d nodes in general) with the node class method (i.e. [CCscene node]) you do not need to release them since they are autorelease objects. However I suggest to override dealloc to removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:TRUE

Hope this helped you